# Creating a Dictionary in C

Tags: c, dictionary

I am currently working on creating a dictionary using a binary search tree-like structure we designed in class.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

struct entry
{
  char* word; 
  unsigned int n; /* n is the number of times the word appears in the source. */
  struct entry *left;
  struct entry *right;
};

/*input_from_args: if no additional argument is given, return stdin. Else, open the text file and read it.*/
FILE*
input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[]){
  if(argc==1){
    return stdin;
  }else{
    return fopen(argv[1],"r");
  }
}
```

Below is the insert function that we also wrote in my class. Given the new word we are looking at, if it is

```
struct entry*
insert(struct entry *table, char* str)
{
  if(table == NULL){
    table = (struct entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    strcpy(table->word,str);
    table -> n = 1;
    table -> left = NULL;
    table -> right = NULL;
  }else if(strcmp(str, table->word) == 0){
    table -> n = (table ->n)+1;
  }else if(strcmp(str, table->word) <0){
    table->left = insert(table->left, str);
  }else if(strcmp(str, table->word) >0){
    table ->right = insert(table->right, str);
  }
  return table;
}
```

Below is a print function which I wrote myself which is to print every word in table and N, the number of times it occurs.

```
void
print_table(struct entry *table){
  if(table!=NULL){
    print_table(table->left);
    printf("%s ", table->word);
    printf("%d \n", table->n);
    print_table(table->right);
  }
}
```

And finally, below is the main function.

```
int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);

  if(src == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  char str[1024];
  struct entry *table;
  int c;
  while((fscanf(src, "%s", str))!= EOF){
    table = insert(table, str);
  }

  print_table(table);

  return 0;

}
```

I'm having some very odd behavior when I run this function. It seems to only be happening when I run it with longer input.
When I run it with this input(in a .txt file):

```
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
```

I get the following output:

```
This 3
a 3
is 3
test 3
```

This is what I should be getting. However, when I give it slightly longer input, such as:

```
Apple Apple
Blue Blue
Cat Cat
Dog Dog
Elder Elder
Funions Funions
Gosh Gosh
Hairy Hairy
```

I get the following output:

```
Appme 2
Blue 2
Cat 2
Dog 2
Elder 2
Funions 2
Gosi 2
Hairy 2
```

Which is clearly correct as far as the numbers go, but why is it changing some of the letters in my words? I gave it Apple, it returned Appme. I gave it Gosh, it gave me Gosi. What's going on with my code that I am missing?

Comment: You are incrementing the characters. `m == l+1` and `i == h+1`.

Comment: Why not step through the code in your debugger and see what's going on ?

Comment: Have you thought about hiring a tutor or talking to the teacher or putting in a lot of printf()'s or using the debugger and taking your time to explore every nook and cranny until you get enough clues to figure it out? That's what coding is all about. If you got this far, you should find the discipline to do the rest.

Comment: Coding is *exactly* about being able to solve problems like this for yourself, and it is very tough sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your insert function, you do not allocate/`malloc()` space for the `word` pointer you are trying to `strcpy()` to:

```
if(table == NULL){
    table = (struct entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    strcpy(table->word,str);
    table -> n = 1;
    table -> left = NULL;
    table -> right = NULL;
}
```

Usually this code would exit with a segmentation fault, because you are copying data to memory you don't own, but this is easy to fix:

```
table->word = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
strcpy(table->word, str);
```

You'll want to allocate one extra byte above the string length, to allow for the null terminator.

You do not need or want to cast the result of `malloc()`. In other words, this is fine:

```
table = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
```

Get into the habit of using `free()` on any pointers you have `malloc()`-ed, when you are done with them. Otherwise, you end up with a memory leak.

Also, compile with `-Wall -Weverything` flags to enable all warnings.

Note: If one absolutely must use `strdup()`, it is easy to write a custom function to do so:

```
char* my_very_own_strdup(const char* src) 
{
    char* dest = NULL;
    if (!src) 
        return dest;
    size_t src_len = strlen(src) + 1;
    dest = malloc(src_len);
    if (!dest) {
        perror("Error: Could not allocate space for string copy\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(dest, src, src_len);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `table->word = strdup(str);` which is equivalent to the malloc -> strcpy.

Comment: Safer to use standard C calls, and having a `malloc()` makes it clear that a `free()` needs to show up at some point. Also, it's useful to know about setting aside space for the null terminator in C strings. Just an opinion.

Comment: **strdup(3)** conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001 (as from the GNU libc manual) and is described also in *K&R first ed* (and after).  I have seen it from the same ancient times of **malloc(3)**.  I have never heard of a C implementation that has support for **malloc(3)**, **strlen(3)** and **strcpy(3)** and not for **strdup(3)**.  Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I don't think it is in some *nix distributions (mingw?) and I don't think it is part of ANSI C. You could easily write your own `strdup()` to make it truly portable, using `malloc()` and `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` to return a `char*`. Sorry for having a differing opinion! :)

Answer (score 3):

This line in the `insert` function is very problematic:

```
strcpy(table->word,str);
```

It's problematic because you don't actually allocate memory for the string. That means that `table->word` is uninitialized and its value will be indeterminate, so the `strcpy` call will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simple solution? Use `strdup` to duplicate the string:

```
table->word = strdup(str);
```

The `strdup` function is not actually in standard C, but just about all platforms have it.

Answer (score 1):

On the line `strcpy(table->word,str);` where is `table->word` allocated?

So It copies only 4 bytes to `table->word` because pointer size is 4-bytes in your machine. So Be careful, you must allocate `table->word` there,

I would use this one instead of that `table->word = strdup(str);`